# How to process capitalisation in words

Tags: python

I tried to solve this problem but don't know how to, I would appreciate it if you could help me.

criteria:
If the paint colour label contains the string 'blue' with any capitalisation, your program should say: 'Excellent! We'll soon have enough paint for the sky!'

I need to know how how to make the code register the capitalisation of the word 'blue'

```
colour = input ('Which colour did you find? ')
number_of_tins = int(input('Number of tins: '))
if 'blue' in colour:
  print ("Excellent! We'll soon have enough paint for the sky!")
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings have a few methods to help you out, namely `lower` and `upper`. Typically `lower` is used in cases like this. It returns a new string of each letter in lowercase or uppercase respectively. So you can simply compare 'blue' to `colour.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert the user input into all lowercase when checking in the if statement.

`if 'blue' in colour.lower()`

The `colour.lower()` makes all the characters in colour lowercase, so you don't really have to complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

In the input you could use methods like `colour = input ('Which colour did you find? ').lower()`

it would convert all your input into lower case
even user type in capital and your program works